# adding a pipe seperator between characters with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a string like 'foobar' which i need to like  be 'f | o | o | b | a | r' in a query (Oracle 12 SQL). That is " | " between each letter but not at the end. The length of the string varies and may be null.

more examples:

'foo'> 'f | o | o'

NULL> ''

I have tried using regexp_replace

```
select regexp_replace(foobar,'.',' | ') from dual
```

and lots of other combinations. I have found examples for regex that don't seem to work in Oracle, like (?<=.)(?!$).

Any help very gratefully received

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`regexp_replace`](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_replace.php)

will do the work:

```
select regexp_replace('foobar','(.)','\1 | ') from dual
```

will give you

```
f | o | o | b | a | r |
```

A simple way to get rid of the last bar (edit, missing the blanks):

```
select substr(regexp_replace('foobar','(.)','\1 | '),1, length('foobar')*4-3) from dual
```

output

```
f | o | o | b | a | r
```

Proof of concept (just to satisfy Raj_te I really don't see what's wrong)

```
with t as 
(
select 1 as id, 'foobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 2 as id, 'fooobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 3 as id, 'foooobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 4 as id, 'fooooobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 5 as id, 'foooooobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 6 as id, 'fooooooobar' as field1 from dual union all
select 7 as id, 'foooooooobar' as field1 from dual )
select substr(regexp_replace(field1,'(.)','\1 | '),1, length(field1)*4-3) 
 from t
 order by id;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
f | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | o | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | o | o | o | o | b | a | r
f | o | o | o | o | o | o | o | o | b | a | r
```

Comment: Why the downvote? It's there something wrong? Constructive criticism is always welcome. ;)

Comment: Lots of good answers but this one fits my real situation best of all.

Comment: @vercelli the answer could be cleaner why use SUBSTR when you can use RTRIM?  Also "foobar" in two places?

Comment: Know-nothings ganging up to badmouth the right answer. Long live SO!

Comment: @mathguy criticism is always good, but if you downvote you should explain why. Thanks for the support ;)

Comment: I didn't mean the downvote, I meant the inept comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you need a back reference to get your character.  Then an additional problem is the `|` at the end of the expression.  Here is one method:

```
select regexp_replace(regexp_replace(foobar, '(.)', '\1 |'), ' \| ', '')
```

Or, perhaps more simply:

```
select substr(regexp_replace(foobar, '(.)', ' | \1'), 4)
```

Comment: This will not work Gordon...In a bit of hurry you forgot single quotes around foobar..!!! Thumb rule..post it when you test it..irrespective of how many reputations you have..!!!

Comment: @Raj_Te . . . The OP's question does not have single quotes around `foobar`, suggesting that it is a column.

Comment: The very first line says "I have a string like 'foobar'  "..So it cannot be a column..

Comment: It was slightly ambiguous on my part!